# Outlook Add In interact with VB Windows Form App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to create an outlook add in where I rightclick on a mail and a special popup menu pops out that interacts with a VB Windows Form App that I also created on Visual studio.

Can anyone please guide me on a few methods that allow me to make such interaction possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know about right-click, but an add-in can be aware of the currently selected message (or calendar, etc.) so that when you launch it from the ribbon you can have access to that outlook item. You might have better luck researching that approach.

Comment: @Crowcoder the question is not about getting the currently selected item in Outlook.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev you may be right, but "rightclick on a mail" implies to me the desire to access that specific message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your VSTO add-in can be treated as a regular .net based application. So, you can use standard .net tools to communicate between two separate applications - your VSTO add-in and Windows Forms application.

If you have an existing WinForms application then I assume you are not using .NET 5 so you can use [Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/conceptual-overview). If you are using .NET 5 or above for WinForms then you cannot use WCF; [gRPC](https://www.codemag.com/Article/1911102/gRPC-as-a-Replacement-for-WCF) is the alternative and it does not work for .Net prior to .Net 5. WCF has been designed as a high-level interface to most options for communications among applications.

If you do not want a client and server then that would be what is called [Peer-to-Peer Networking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/peer-to-peer-networking).

After choosing the technology to communicate between two applications you can grab the currently selected item by using ribbon callbacks. Typically the `onAction` callback for button controls has the following signature:

```
C#: void OnAction(IRibbonControl control)
VBA: Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl)
C++: HRESULT OnAction([in] IRibbonControl *pControl)
Visual Basic: Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl)
```

You can use the [IRibbonControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribboncontrol) instance passed as a parameter to get the [Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribboncontrol.context) property value which represents the active window containing the Ribbon user interface that triggers a callback procedure. After that you can get the `Selection` object and process the selected item clicked.

Comment: There is no need for WCF or gRPC. The Add-In can host a Form that has access to the outlook API.

Comment: Yes, the add-in can have a form onboard. We don't know all the conditions. But the caption says about interaction of two.